# SONAR-metrics of test cases

Tags: sonarqube, metrics

I am running Sonar using Maven to calculate software metrics. However, Sonar does not show size, complexity, efferent couplings for the test cases. Do I need change any settings? or Sonar only calculates metrics for source code?

Comment: Please do not double post. Already answered at http://sonar.15.x6.nabble.com/SONAR-metrics-of-test-cases-td5016693.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sonar -LOC & Cyclomatic complexity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19178315/sonar-loc-cyclomatic-complexity)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19178315/sonar-loc-cyclomatic-complexity and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19216537/sonar-overall-coverage -- Please don't double-post your questions.