# Sonar-Overall Coverage

Tags: code-coverage, sonarqube, metrics

Sonar gives a value of Overall coverage which is a combination of line and branch coverage. I am not sure how important is this metric. What does the value of overall coverage signifies? How it is better than line and branch coverage? Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 5):

From Sonar's documentation:

> It is a mix of Line coverage and Condition coverage. Its goal is to
>   provide an even more accurate answer to the following question: How
>   much of the source code has been covered by the unit tests?

```
Coverage = (CT + CF + LC)/(2*B + EL)

where

CT = conditions that have been evaluated to 'true' at least once
CF = conditions that have been evaluated to 'false' at least once
LC = covered lines = lines_to_cover - uncovered_lines

B = total number of conditions
EL = total number of executable lines (lines_to_cover)
```

Source: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Metric+Definitions#MetricDefinitions-Tests

Answer (score 2):

Here's how the overall coverage is computed: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Metric+Definitions#MetricDefinitions-Tests

If branch coverage is lower than line coverage (and thus lower than overall coverage), it means that your unit tests test the main cases but not really the corner cases.

Comment: Thanks David! If overall coverage is combination of line and branch coverage, how these fractions are added? I am still not sure about the difference between line and overall coverage since both measure the amount of code covered.

Comment: This answer is incomplete. There is a Coverage metric, which is indeed the combination of line and branch coverage as described. But the overall_coverage metric is a combination of integration test coverage(it_coverage) and unit test coverage(coverage). If either test covers a line or condition it is counted as covered.