# Overall coverage metrics does not reflect my local results

Tags: javascript, typescript, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

We have a mix of javascript and typescript sources in our project which is being reported on in our SonarQube instance.

Up until recently we were running a pure javascript codebase and so were using the default javascript plugin with Sonar for our metrics.

Having now migrated much of our code to typescript we have configured the SonarTsPlugin (https://github.com/Pablissimo/SonarTsPlugin) and have two lcov files being generated (using gulp & istanbul), so one for our js sources and the other for the ts.

Our combined coverage when viewing our results locally come in at over 95% (using gulp istanbul-combine), but when SonarQube applies its calculations after reading the lcov files, it shows the overall coverage at just below 90%. I have seen other posts explaining how Sonar computes its overall figure - [Sonar-Overall Coverage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19216537/sonar-overall-coverage)

I'm trying to figure out why there is such a big difference however.

We use Jenkins with their sonar scanner plugin and when looking at the build log whilst it's connecting to our Sonar instance and publishing results, I see the following:

[image]

The overall coverage sensor seems to only kick in after the lov file related to the javascript sources is being read.

The sensor doesn't seem to trigger again when the karma-remapped-coverage.json file for our typsecript sources is read further down in the log. I wondered could this be the reason I'm seeing such differences?

Answer (score 1):

You don't list your SonarQube version, but 6.2 includes "force coverage to 0" functionality (for languages where the analyzers feed the requisite "executable lines" data). Standard coverage reports entirely ignore files on which there are *no* tests.

Assume I have 10 files, each with 100 lines. Eight of them are 100% tested, and two of them have no tests at all. Standard coverage reports will say I have 100% coverage, when coverage is actually at 80%.

SonarQube 6.2's "force coverage to 0" functionality gives you that more accurate picture which is more than likely why you're seeing a lower aggregate coverage number in SonarQube.

Comment: Hmm ok, we are on version 5.6 and there won't be any planned upgrades by our infrastructure team for some time I don't think.

Comment: IIRC 5.6 included a faulty version of 'force coverage to zero', so it's still possible that that's the explanation

Comment: Having just read the docs, Im confused about this force zero coverage setting and why you think it would help me here - https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/JavaScript+Coverage+Results+Import It says if an lcov report is specified it will prevail over the force zero coverage setting, so it sounds like this wont help me since I am supply lcov paths for Sonar to use

Comment: Then I misremembered. Perhaps you should edit your question to include versions. Then I'll drop my answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks. After some further digging I think I have found some further clues as to why I am seeing differences but it needs to be a new question!